# Identify and count lines of Java code in JSPs to help drive unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, jsp, intellij-idea, code-coverage

I'm trying to increase unit testing for a large code base that several different teams actively work on.  Much of the code was inherited, and none of it had unit tests to begin with.  Additionally, it is common to find large blocks of Java code in JSPs.  I've been advocating that developers **not** put Java code in JSPs, but put it in Java classes instead to make unit testing much easier (and for the other reasons this makes sense).

While I can get code coverage data *for the code in Java classes* with the unit tests we have, **I don't have a way to know how much Java code exists in JSPs** (which has zero code coverage by existing unit tests).  We are using the latest version of Intellij, though I don't think the solution necessarily needs to be constrained by that.

I'd like to know the total number of lines of Java code--including those lines found in JSPs--so I can get a comprehensive code coverage number for the Java code, whether it is in JSPs or Java classes.  Having something to track will help me evangelize unit testing.

**Is there an automated way to get the total line count for Java code, whether it exists in JSPs or Java classes?**

Comment: Check out [cloc](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) and [SONAR](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Plugin+Library;jsessionid=7DA02B5F338C4DB29C87D37501C884FB). You will have to incorporate them into your build tool of course.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an automated method and I would be surprised if one is out there.

- No one intended to test the code coverage of scriptlets since like
  you mentioned, scriptlets are horrible abominations.
- Scriptlets are not written these days, so it is unlikely that
  there is a tool out there (open source / commercial ) that will fit
  the bill.

Some approaches I can think of

- Write a HTML parser that will scrap out the scriptlet. This might
  turn out to be difficult since I suspect the `<%= //code =>` will be
  converted into their text forms. They are not valid tags, but you can still benefit from some parsing.
- Compile the JSP using Jasper or an equivalent framework and use their
  API methods to get scriptlet information about the JSP page. ( I'll
  confess that hunting for API methods / member variables that can
  reveal this data is not trivial. )
- Write your own parser that will scan a file for the `<%=` characters
  and start counting lines of code for every /n and /r/n character encountered until a `%>` is
  reached.

I think writing your own parser is probably the easiest way to go about it.

There may be another way to approach the problem. You could use a tool like google [CodePro](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/features/audit/audit_rules_com.instantiations.assist.eclipse.auditGroup.jsp) to audit your JSP files. Try [creating a custom rule](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/features/audit/audit_adding_new_rules) that prohibits JSP scriptlets.

Comment: What, you don't test your abominations?  How can you know if they are right?

Comment: I'd rather move them to JSP custom tags than spend time testing them. If you did want to test the result from a JSP page, you need a tool like selenium anyway. Tracking the number of lines of scriptlets is one thing. Trying to get code coverage numbers on scriptlets is something else all together.